# How to create a sample "helloworld site" using Oracle web center sites 11g?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, webcenter-sites, fatwire

I am new to web center sites.We have completed the setup process for web center sites.I have been studying the developer guide and also searched in google but nowhere I am able to get a clear description of all this.I found one of the videos to create a sample but that was for 12c version.I have not installed jumpstart kit and eclipse, want to develop the site using web center sites interface.I have the admin credentials.

So anybody working in web center sites,Please help me.

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, you should be more precise. I have no online guide to help you but I was in the same situation some years ago and I can feel your distress. Try to understand first what are the asset types and assets concept. Once you understood that you have to create flex families and define all your assets attributes and definitions you'll be able to start creating a "site" and place pages. Then you'll have to enable your asset types on the website and create start menus. To start displaying assets you'll need to design templates for your asset types. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can study the AviSports sample site for a decent example of how to implement a site. Be aware, though, that there is no one-true-way to implement a site. There are many different approaches and patterns, depending on your requirements. You would be well advised to seek direct assistance from an experienced consultant.